# Importing standard modules in ironpython script in silverlight application raises an error

Tags: python, silverlight, ironpython, python-import

Can someone explain, please, how to avoid errors of type: **"ImportError: No module named nameOfModule"**
in **ironpython** script, which is part of Silverlight web application? 
The error pops, even when I try to import standard modules like **os, sys**, but not **re** for example. It happens when I load my web page in the browser.
When, I tried to print **"sys.path"** in the **"IronPython console"** inside browser, [] is returned.
One of the possible solutions was to manually copy **os.py, sys.py** and so on to the project folder, then editing the  html file of the web page with lines like:

```
script type="text/python" src="os.py"></script>
```

But, this is not a good way, as I have to do it for all the python modules, which the imported modules use.

Thank you in advance.